# Facing this issue everytime I run the app: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Tags: java, android

I am  Facing this error every time I try to run the app, tried to resolve it for days but no result, Reviewed most of the questions that have my same issue but still no results

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.appevents.InternalAppEventsLogger
                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 18 more
             Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Here is the list of solutions I did already:

- Deleted .gradle folder
- Rebuild project > clean project
- Did a way back revert for my whole project
- Disabled Instant Run

Here is my `.build gradle`

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'



      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also the classloader.java shows errors when I navigate to the error.

Hope to have a solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try invalidate cache and restart in Android Studio.

Click on File -> Invalidate Cache and Select Invalidate and Restart.

And also check that your app has Internet permission.

If above doesn't work then Try 4.39.0 as FB SDK version

If using proguard then add this to proguard rules

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.facebook.**
```

**Update**:
Try 4.39.0 as FB SDK version. It should do the trick.

Comment: Finally found a solution, anyone facing the same issue can try this, Thank you buddy!